# Python Decorators, Flask, Args

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-decorators, functools

I am wondering why when I go to the route '/al6759@school.edu/info', the console prints

```
()
al6759@school.edu
```

Why is args empty even though user_info is sent a value? I tried to provide the least amount of code necessary to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from functools import wraps


def security(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


@app.route('/<email>/info', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@security
def user_info(email):
    print(email)
    return render_template('user_info.html')
```

Comment: `print(kwargs)` might be illuminating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to print `kwargs['email']` in your decorator.

So this for example:

```
def security(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):

        print('email from kwargs: ', kwargs['email'])
        print('kwargs: ', kwargs)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Will give the output:

```
email from kwargs:  al6759@school.edu
kwargs:  {'email': 'al6759@school.edu'}
al6759@school.edu
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! How come its placed in kwargs not args?